# Superelliptic curves for eigenvalue problems?

Tags: algebraic-curves

A superelliptic curve is defined by the equation 
\begin{equation}
y^n - P(x) = 0 
\end{equation}
for some $n \geq 2$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of order $m$ in $x$. This equation can be thought of as defining a one (complex-) dimensional hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$.

Now, one can think of a more general equation $Q(x,y) = 0$, where $Q$ is a polynomial of order $m(n)$ in $x(y)$, respectively. This equation also defines a one (complex-) dimensional hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^1 \times \mathbb{CP}^1$. Have such curves been studied? Or is there a straightforward way of reducing $Q(x)$ to the defining equation of the superellptic curves?

In particular, I have a matrix-valued function $M \colon \mathbb{CP}^1 \to \text{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})$, such that the entries of $M(x)$ are polynomials in $x$. I am interested in the topological properties (the genus, for instance) of the complex curve defined by the corresponding characteristic polynomial $Q(x,y) = \det[y - M(x)]$. Has anyone come across this setup by any chance?

Comment: The particular case is a special cases of Determinantal variety.

Comment: These curves have been studied a lot. Look to any book with the title Algebraic curves, or Algebraic functions. The general case cannot be reduced to the special case that you mention in the beginning.